# API Route available with Any token JWT+PASSPORT

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, passport.js

I'm building api for my app and trying to use passport jwt.
I can register new users and login(get the token back) but when I use the Postman to check the "protected" route I can use Any Token like this 'any any'
**Pasport.js**

```
const   JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy,
        ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;

const   User = require('../api/models/user/userModel'),// load up the user model
        config = require('../config/database'); // get db config file

module.exports = (passport)=> {
    let opts = {};
    opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeader();
    opts.secretOrKey = config.secret;
    passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, function(jwt_payload, done) {
        User.findOne({id: jwt_payload.id}, (err, user)=> {
            if (err) {
                return done(err, false);
            }
            if (user) {
                done(null, user);
            } else {
                done(null, false);
            }
        });
    }));
};
```

**Server.js**

```
const   express = require('express'),
        app = express(),
        port = process.env.PORT || 3000,
        mongoose = require('mongoose'),
        morgan = require('morgan'),
        passport = require('passport'),
        bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
        jwt = require('jsonwebtoken'),
        config = require('./config/database'),
        Event = require('./api/models/event/eventModel'),
        User = require('./api/models/user/userModel');


mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

mongoose.connect(config.database);

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(passport.initialize());

/* Routers registration */

const routesEvent = require('./api/routes/event/eventRoutes');
routesEvent(app);

const routesUser = require('./api/routes/user/userRoutes');
routesUser(app);

/* END Routers registration */

/* Express middleware
 * which used to return more interactive messages */

app.use((req, res, next)=>{
    res.status(404).send({url: req.originalUrl + ' not found'});
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});

/* END Express middleware */

// Launch the server on port 3000
const server = app.listen(3000, () => {
    const { address, port } = server.address();
    console.log(`RESTful API server Listening at http://${address}:${port}`);
});
```

**EventRouter.js**

```
const   jwt = require('jsonwebtoken'),
    passport = require('passport');

require('../../../config/passport')(passport); // as strategy in ./passport.js needs passport object

module.exports = (app)=> {
    const event = require('../../controllers/event/eventController');

    // Routes
    app.route('/events' )
        .get( event.list_all_events, passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false}));

};
```

**EventController**

```
const   mongoose = require('mongoose'),
        Event = mongoose.model('Events'),
        getToken = require('../../../config/getToken');

exports.list_all_events = (req, res)=> {
    let token = getToken(req.headers);
    if(token){
        Event.find({}, (err, event)=> {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);
            res.json(event);
        });
    } else {
        return res.status(403).send({success: false, msg: 'Unauthorized.'});
    }

};
```

I'm definitely doing something wrong in controller or in this file
**GetToken.js**

```
module.exports = getToken = (headers)=> {
    console.log(headers);
    if (headers && headers.authorization) {
        let parted = headers.authorization.split(' ');
//Here I can see my Token from the Postman
        if (parted.length === 2) {
            return parted[1];
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } else {
        return null;
    }
};
```

Please, any ideas about a mistake that I'm making above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks strange but when I changed code to this

```
EventRouter.js

app.route('/events' )
        .get(  passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false}), event.list_all_events)
        .post(event.create_event);
```

It's works like expected
The only one difference is the order in get(passport, function)

Answer (score 1):

Below line act as an middle ware. It is validating JWT token, once token is validated it will call `JwtStrategy` and setting user object in request and then it will call the actual function which is suppose to be executed.

```
passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false})
```

You really do not need getToken function. It will be taken care by above line. If token is not validated then above line automatically returns 401.